# How to setup a cumulative count grouped by month with underlying conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've come across somewhat of an interesting scenario where I'm needing to aggregate enrollment counts and group them by the individual month and all subsequent months leading up to the completion date. The starting counter will be placed into the month when the enrollment began, and now I'm needing to set up a cumulative sum to carry out the single count.

Here's a couple of test records I'm working with
[image]

I've set up the following query to compile the date_month CTE to compile the full 12 months derived from my Start/End Range variables. I've then joined it to my test table in order to establish the Counter placements.

```
DECLARE @EnrollmentDateStart DATETIME  = '2020-01-01'
DECLARE @EnrollmentDateEnd DATETIME  = '2020-12-01'

;WITH CTE_Months(year_month) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @EnrollmentDateStart), 0))
  FROM ( SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @EnrollmentDateStart, @EnrollmentDateEnd) + 1) 
    n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1
    FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id] ) AS n
)
SELECT
  [Year]     = YEAR(cm.year_month),
  [Month]    = DATENAME(MONTH, cm.year_month), 
  SUM(IIF(tt.[Enrollment Start Date] >= @EnrollmentDateStart,1,0)) AS EnrollmentCount
FROM CTE_Months cm
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #TMP_Testing_Table tt
    ON tt.[Enrollment Start Date] >= cm.year_month
    AND tt.[Enrollment Start Date] < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cm.year_month)
GROUP BY tt.Department, cm.year_month
```

At this stage, I'm pulling back the following results, so I now have the Enrollment Counts placed into the correct starting months derived from the Enrollment Start Date.

[image]

Now I'm trying to figure out what would be the best course of action to place the subsequent count for the additional months leading up to the Completion date?

For example - The first User (UserId: 1) was Enrolled in March, 2020, and Completed in August, 2020, so essentially I'm looking to produce the following result to reflect the number of months ranging between March <> July (Last month prior to Completion)

January: 0
February: 0
March: 1
April: 1
May: 1
June: 1
July: 1
August: 0
September: 0
October: 0
November: 0
December: 0

Thinking a cumulative total should be able to address the subsequent for the month by month range, however, I would then need to zero out the total for all subsequent months on and after the recorded Completion date for this record in question.

Seeing if I can get your thoughts/suggestions on how to address this scenario? Apologies if the information/explanation is confusing, but please let me know, and I'll do my best to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
....................    
SELECT
  [Year]     = YEAR(cm.year_month),
  [Month]    = DATENAME(MONTH, cm.year_month), 
  count(tt.userid) AS EnrollmentCount
FROM CTE_Months cm
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #TMP_Testing_Table tt on cm.year_month > eomonth([Enrollment Start Date], -1) 
           and cm.year_month <= tt.[Enrollment End Date]
GROUP BY cm.year_month
```

Comment: Thanks, the rolling counter along with the End Of Month function is working great, however, I'm still working out a few ways to get the enrollment count set to 0 for the Month of August (last recorded completion date) for the one enrollment.

Comment: @Curtis ... i missed that. You could try the EOMONTH() for the [End Date] too: EOMONTH([End Date], if End Date in the same month as Start Date then 0 else -1)

Comment: Sure, I'll give that a go as well. I've come up with a way to place this into a nested CTE, and then apply a minus calculation when Enrollment Month == Completion month for each record as well. For the most part, the suggestion helped me out, so I've marked yours as the accepted answer. Thanks for your help on this.